# Angular 7 accessing component directly is not loading Child Components

Tags: angular, components, angular7

I have a parent component called "ReportComponent" with a child component "PortCriteriaComponent".  When I start form the home page (localhost: 8080/home), and Click on the link to Port Reports, the parent and child components will load.  However, if I go to the parent component directly (localhost:8080/reports/4005, the child components will NOT load.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-va12km

Comment: I'm not sure the stackblitz accurately shows the problem, but I'm betting it's your lack of a router.

Comment: You must use <router-oulet> directive in order to render components inside your app. I recomend you read this: https://angular.io/guide/router